# Why does my laptop think it's the year 2112 after the battery reaches 0% charge?

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, clock

When my laptop's battery reaches 0% charge, the next time I boot the system clock resets itself to January 1, 2112. I'm wondering:

1. Aside from the possibility my laptop is a huge RUSH fan, why would 2112 be the year to which the system clock reverts?
2. How can I prevent this from happening every time my battery dies? (I know how to fix it manually, see below.)

Just in case anyone is stuck in a similar situation, the manual fix on Linux is to run something like the following as root:

```
# date -s "7 OCT 2020 12:51:00"
```

This sets the hardware clock in UTC time; depending on how your time and timezone is configured, you may need to set hardware in local time instead. I'll add that setting system time based off network time won't work in this situation because DHCP refuses to give this laptop an IP address when it's claiming the year is 2112, so it can't connect to the internet until the clock is fixed.

---

System specs:

- Laptop is a Jumper EZBook X3.
- Debian 10 using i3wm for a window manager.

Comment: Perhaps replace the motherboard CMOS Battery. If it is not good the clock can be reset.

Comment: Maybe not your computer that's a Rush fan, but instead the developer of the clock. I occasionally do things like this, e.g. make a default value something recognizable (Pi, 0xDEADBEEF, etc.) so I can quickly see if a value has not been set correctly. Seeing the year as 2112 is an instant red flag that the clock was reset. It's also unlikely that particular clock will still be in use in the year 2112, so the default value will always be useful as an intentionally invalid value.

Comment: BTW, do **not** let a battery go to zero charge, particularly Li-ion batteries. Each time it is stressed like that damages the cells a bit, and shortens its life. Most OS prevent that from happening by forcing shutdown at 10 or 15%.

Comment: That's really good to know, DrMoishe Pippik. I thought the concern there was just not losing any user data stored in RAM; based on the way I use this laptop I don't typically have valuable data floating only in memory. I'll look into adding some protection.